# Refresh Activity when item select in BottomSheet Fragment

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet, android-bottomappbar

I have set up a `BottomAppBar` with a `NavigationDrawer` but I can't recover the item selected in this Drawer which is a fragment.

I followed many tutorials to set up this `BottomAppBar` but at no time did I see how to get the selection from the Drawer.

Here is how my Drawer is created:

```
public class MaintainerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maintainer);

        setUpBottomAppBar();
    }

    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void setUpBottomAppBar() {
        BottomAppBar bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bottom_app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(bottomAppBar);

        bottomAppBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = BottomSheetNavigationMaintainerFragment.newInstance();
                bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment");
                Bundle args = bottomSheetDialogFragment.getArguments();
            }
        });

        bottomAppBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the code of my fragment:

```
public class BottomSheetNavigationMaintainerFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    public BottomSheetNavigationMaintainerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static BottomSheetNavigationMaintainerFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        BottomSheetNavigationMaintainerFragment fragment = new BottomSheetNavigationMaintainerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) { }
    };

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        //Get the content View
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_bottom_navigation_maintainer, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);

        NavigationView navigationView = contentView.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        //implement navigation menu item click event
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.app_bar_assets:
                        break;
                    case R.id.app_bar_items:
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        ImageView closeButton = contentView.findViewById(R.id.close_image_view);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //dismiss bottom sheet
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        //Set the coordinator layout behavior
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();

        //Set callback
        if (behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
            ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        }
    }
}
```

I would therefore like to return the selected item in the `onNavigationItemSelected` method but I can't find a way to link this fragment to my activity in which it is created

Comment: Why don't you do it by invoking a method on the activity from the bottom sheet? Something like this: `((MaintainerActivity)getActivity()).doSomethingInTheActivity()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding one fragment in activity. in which fragment I call bottomFragment on button click open a bottom sheet and on click of bottom bar text the toast print in the fragment.
Create Dialog class with a click event interface

```
  public class AutoAppSelectrDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

        OnAutoAppSelectPickerListener mListener;

        /**
         * Factory method.
         *
         * @return A new instance of fragment ImagePickerDialogFragment.
         */
        public static AutoAppSelectrDialogFragment newInstance(boolean showRemove) {
            AutoAppSelectrDialogFragment fragment = new AutoAppSelectrDialogFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putBoolean("showRemove", showRemove);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        @Override
        public void setupDialog(final Dialog dialog, int style) {
            super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
            View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.bottom_sheet_auto_run, null);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, contentView);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.setContentView(contentView);
        }

        public void setListener(OnAutoAppSelectPickerListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }


        @OnClick(R.id.txt_1)
        public void Click1() {
            if (mListener != null)
                mListener.onClick1();
            dismiss();
        }

        @OnClick(R.id.txt_2)
        public void Click2() {
            if (mListener != null)
                mListener.onClick2();
            dismiss();
        }




        public interface OnAutoAppSelectPickerListener {
            void onClick1();
            void onClick2();
        }

    }
```

XML of dialogue Fragment layout bottom_sheet_auto_run

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp_12"
                android:textColor="@color/content_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_16_sp" />

<TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp_12"
                android:textColor="@color/content_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_16_sp" />
```

Open Bottom Sheet Dialogue on click of a button in fragment or activity like this and using a interface to implement an on click event of DialougeFragment layout

```
    public class AutoSartInformation extends Fragment implements AutoAppSelectrDialogFragment.OnAutoAppSelectPickerListener {
      @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    imgAutoStartApp = view.findViewById(R.id.img_auto_start_app);
     imgAutoStartApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AutoAppSelectrDialogFragment imagePickerDialogFragment = AutoAppSelectrDialogFragment.newInstance(true);
                    imagePickerDialogFragment.setCancelable(false);
                    imagePickerDialogFragment.setListener(AutoSartInformation.this);
                    imagePickerDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), imagePickerDialogFragment.getTag());
                }
            });
       }


    @Override
    public void onClick1() {
      Log.d("Click","1");
open Fragment on click of dialouge first text click
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick2() {
        Log.d("Click","2");
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing
I want to load a fragment in my activty that depends on the item selected in the drawer
Check my code I edited my post

Comment: Hm but I think `mListener` will be null after process death, so user presses button1/button2 and nothing will happen.

Answer (score 4):

How about introducing an interface like:

```
public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
   void onItemSelected(int ItemId);
}
```

Make the MaintainerActivity implement this interface like this:

```
public class MaintainerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(int ItemId) {
      //TODO - do something with this selected item...
   }
}
```

And then in your BottomSheetNavigationMaintainerFragment do this:

```
private OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
   super.onAttach(context);
   if(context instanceof OnItemSelectedListener){
        onItemSelectedListener = (OnItemSelectedListener)context;
   }
}
```

Then, when an item is selected:

```
//implement navigation menu item click event 
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
          if(onItemSelectedListener != null){
              onItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(item.getItemId());
          }
          return false;
       }
    });
```